# Why the size of a decoded package in ffmpeg would be zero?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I was reading the code of decoding a byte stream from a video.
But I am a bit confused that the size of packet could be 0 sometimes.
What does it mean? And if it is zero, what's the information these bytes carries?

```
int len = av_parser_parse2(
        pCodecParserCtx, pCodecCtx,
        &packet.data, &packet.size,
        cur_ptr , cur_size ,
        AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE);
    cur_ptr += len;
    cur_size -= len;

if (packet.size==0)
  continue;
```

Comment: It may be an audio frame. Just to make sure. You should filter your data before sending it to the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official document](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/group__lavc__parsing.html#ga691ca0258e91f99297e7726f56d8c247), the packet size will be set to zero if a packet is not yet obtained and the parser needs more input data.